# windows phone 8 popup width and height

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am placing a grid in a popup control. I expected the grid to be re-sized automatically according to the 3 different layout sizes for windows phone 8 apps (**480 × 800, 768 × 1280, 720 × 1280**).

But it seems like i would have to set the **width and height** of the grid **explicitly** because it's re-sizing itself according to child control size whereas i wanted the popup box to be shown as full with on the top of the screen for all three resolutions.

Any Help?

Comment: Show the code you are using for the Grid and Popup controls. Then it would be much better to answer

Answer (score 29):

The easiest way to get a full screen popup to work on WP8 is by setting the Child width & height to the phone's current logical resolution. You can read more about [WP8 Multi-resolution zen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470605/wp8-emulator-screen-size/13473129#13473129) here and learn more about [WP8 Multi-resolution APIs](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Multi_resolution) here.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myPopup = new Popup()
    {
        Child = new Border()
        {
            Child = new TextBlock()
                    {
                        Text = "Hello World!"
                    },
            Height =  Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight,
            Width =  Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
        }
    };

    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myPopup);
    myPopup.IsOpen = true; 
}
```

This code snippet is a bit overzealous since shell items (e.g. SystemTray, AplicaitonBar, etc) can take space away from your rendering area.

Here's a print screen of the code snippet above executing in the WXGA emulator:

[image: Full screen popup on WXGA]

And here's the code snippet above executing in the 720P emulator: 
[image: Full screen popup on 720P]

Comment: How would you do this in XAML?