# WP8: no popup available?

Tags: popup, windows-phone-8

I'd like to programm a tiny popup to get some user input (a textarea, a input field and two buttons). What component could host these components? Apparently there is no `Popup` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one basic popup

```
<Popup  Name="m_Popup"  IsOpen="False" Opened="OnPoputOpen" Closed="OnPopupClose" >
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height ="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>                                
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 

            <TextBox Name="m_TextBox" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button Name="m_Button1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Name="m_Button2" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
```

You control the visibility with `IsOpen`. Here is a link to [Popup Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Good luck (:

Comment: The link you provided specifically says **Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0**, so I don't think it will work in WP8 (Although I wouldn't be able to actually check until tonight).

Comment: It appears you are right. I found another article here that shows an example of using it (in this example the user wanted a full-screen popup, though). You can check it out though for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029639/windows-phone-8-popup-width-and-height

Comment: I'm totally confused by this funny component library. Never seen such an absolute mess. 
Thank you for the link.
All you have to is:
`System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup NewItemPopup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();`
In my VS 2012 Express `System.Windows.Controls` is *not* included automatically. Only MS knows why!

Answer (score -5):

No, this is not provided in the SDK. You have to build it yourself.