# Info menu upon Hold for Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to create some kind of info menu when a button has triggered the event *Hold*. I've looked a bit into the ContextMenu, but this does not close automatically when the you stop holding. What I want is a PopUp, or a similar thing which shows some kind of info when the button event *Hold* is pressed, and closes when it is no more "Holded". Is this possible and in that case what should I use?

Comment: Well that seems a little counter intuitive. Whats wrong with having the user clear the popup with a tap like usual?

Comment: Why it is used on computers, so why not,on Phones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess a solution could be to use popup as you say. So when the hold event is fired you show a popup by using the position of your finger. When the user releases the screen the manipulation ended event should be fired, then you can use a boolean to check if it was a hold event or not.

If it was a hold event then you close the popup, or delete it, if you need to remove it from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) Class to display any kind of message or whatever the option you want.

Refer some of these samples:

[Popup in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322449/)

[WP8: no popup available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363245/)

For the hold event you could use the [toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/):

XAML:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
     <toolkit:GestureListener Hold="GroupItem_Hold"/>
 </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu>

                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove Group" Click="removeGroup"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

.cs:

```
  private void removeGroup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        //do something here
        }

 private void GroupItem_Hold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
        var holdItem = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as Usergroup;

        App.selectedGroup = holdItem.id.ToString();

        grp_name = holdItem.groupName;
        }
```

I used the above code to get the details of an item from a listbox when a user holds on that particular item.

Hope it helps :)