# How to full Screen popup in windows phone 8?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, telerik, windows-phone-8

Hi;
i can not fit RadModalWindow on windows phone 8 application. How to fill all screen my popup?

```
 <telerikPrimitives:RadModalWindow Name="cardselect" IsFullScreen="True"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel}"
                                          IsClosedOnOutsideTap="True">
                <Grid Name="ModalWindowGrid1"
                      Width="{Binding ProgramtDetailWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Height="{Binding ProgramtDetailHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Background.png"/>
                    </Grid.Background>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FF0A0611" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="2">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF45374D"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF1E092A" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="330" Height="392" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF2F1F3"/>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="330" Margin="-3,0" >
                                <StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Height="385">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF2F1F3"/>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,22,0,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="21.333" Height="32" Width="209" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="Dijital Kart No Seçiniz"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel x:Name="WaitingPanel" Margin="0,60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Kayıt işlemi sürüyor." VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="21.333" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <ProgressBar x:Name="pgb" Width="250" IsIndeterminate="True" Margin="0,10
                             ,0,0" Value="0"  />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Grid x:Name="grdClient" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="313" Width="329">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="255*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="58*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="46" Margin="0,0,21,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="119" Click="btnRecord_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Vazgeç" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" Margin="21,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="119" Click="btnCancel_Click_1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <ListBox Name="lstCards" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" Margin="21,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListBox>

                                    </Grid>


                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadModalWindow>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029639/windows-phone-8-popup-width-and-height

Comment: also check this out http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/media-player/fullscreen-problem-urgent.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your window's content is not big enough to fill the screen. The RadModalWindow does fill the whole screen, but any area not covered by your content will show what is behind it via transparency.

Make your main grid auto size to fill the screen. Alternately, setting a background colour or image on your window should ensure the transparency doesn't show the content behind the window.