# Change the phone editor resolution?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

How can I change the resolution of the phone representing the code when in xaml view in a project?

The phone serves as a drag and drop for the controls, does it have a setting somewhere to set it's resolution. Windows Phone 8 currently have three resolutions; 800x480, 1280x720 and 1280x768.

I'm aware the emulator can be started up with different resolution, but my situation is that my CPU does not support this, im debugging straight on my Lumia 920 (1280x768). 
I've got no clue on how the application looks like in 800x480.

But it is a simple application, a preview would be good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the Device Window: Design -> Device Window

There under the display section you can select the display size (3 available).

Additionally you can test any other resolution by disabling the 'Chrome' option in the device window and setting d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth of your page to the desired resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem and after much time searching google and stackoverflow, I don't think that it is possible to change the resolution of the designer window. However, maybe this link can help you, it helped me back a while ago when I had that problem:

[WP8 Emulator screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470605/wp8-emulator-screen-size)

It refers to the emulator, but explains how the app UI will be scaled to match different device resolutions. Hope it helps!